# How to create dual prefix and read POST payload with DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to execute an SSH command using a POST method. The command and its parameters are specified in the POST request’s JSON payload.

I have no idea on how to acompplish this using the DefaultRouter from django REST framework

**So my first question is; How do I create a route or view for this url?**

```
POST http://127.0.0.1/datacenter/<datacenter_id>/<server_id>/ssh/
```

**And, how do I get the data from the payload in order to work with it?**

I've tried with something like this;

```
@detail_route(methods=['POST'])
def ssh(self, request, pk=None):
    print request.data
```

but Im getting "Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<type 'NoneType'>`"

**models.py**

```
class Datacenter(models.Model):

    # Parent data

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Servers(models.Model):

    datacenter = models.ForeignKey(Datacenter)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.hostname
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ServerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Server

class DatacenterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    servers = ServerSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Datacenter
        fields = ('id', 'servers')
```

**views.py**

```
class DatacenterViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Datacenter.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DatacenterSerializer

class ServerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Server.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ServerSerializer
```

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'Datacenter', views.DatacenterViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code seems to be nearly-complete. Assuming that you have a function that does the actual execution (let's call it "run_ssh_command"), a rudimentary version of your view could look something like this:

```
@detail_route(methods=['POST'])
def ssh(self, request):
    input = json.loads(request.data)  # I'd use a serializer here
    output = run_ssh_command(input['command'])  # or whatever the field name is
    return Response(json.dumps({'result': output}),
                            content_type="application/json")
```

Some caveats:

1. Make sure you use proper authentication,
2. Keep in mind that some SSH commands might take a while to run OR they may just hang (E.G., waiting for input),
3. Take a look at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/ for an example on how to use Serializers for request validation.

Comment: Sorry, no its not running, I'm getting: 'expected string or buffer'